# One dimensional heat equation

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, boundary-value-problem

Let $\Omega
 =(0,1)$
  and $\nu>0$
 . We consider the one dimensional heat equation

$(1)$ $\dfrac{\partial u\left(x,t\right)}{\partial t}-\nu\dfrac{\partial^{2}u\left(x,t\right)}{\partial x^{2}}=0,x\in\Omega,t>0$

together with homogeneous Neumann boundary conditions

$(2)$ $ \dfrac{\partial u}{\partial x}\left(0,t\right)=\dfrac{\partial u}{\partial x}\left(1,t\right)=0,\forall t>0$

and the initial condition

$(3)$ $u\left(x,t=0\right)=u_{0}$

where $u_{0}$
  is a given function belonging to $L^{2}\left(\Omega\right)$
 .

Prove that for $v(x,t)$
  smooth enough and $v$ is a solution of that equation

$2{\displaystyle \int}_{\left[0,1\right]}\dfrac{\partial v(x,t)}{\partial t}v(x,t)dx={\displaystyle \int}_{\left[0,1\right]}\dfrac{\partial}{\partial t}v^{2}(x,t)dx=\dfrac{d}{dt}\displaystyle \int_{0}^{1}v^{2}(x,t)dx$

Help me some hints, pls. Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Multiply the equation by $v$ and integrate by parts.
$$
v\,v_t-\nu\,v\,v_{xx}=0.
$$
Integrate between $0$ and $1$:
$$
\int_0^1v\,v_t\,dx-\nu\int_0^1\,v\,v_{xx}\,dx=0.
$$
Integrate by parts:
$$
\frac12\int_0^1(v^2)_t\,dx-\nu\Bigl(v\,v_x\Bigr|_0^1-\int_0^1(v_{x})^2\,dx\Bigr)=0.
$$

Comment: Could you precise your idea with more details?

Comment: Is precise enough now?

Comment: I only see ${\displaystyle \int}_{\left[0,1\right]}\dfrac{\partial}{\partial t}v^{2}(x,t)dx$, how about $2{\displaystyle \int}_{\left[0,1\right]}\dfrac{\partial v(x,t)}{\partial t}v(x,t)dx$ and  $\dfrac{d}{dt}\displaystyle \int_{0}^{1}v^{2}(x,t)dx$?

Comment: Just take the derivative out of the integral.